# How to obtain ToTraceString for IQueryable.Count

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-to-entities, expression-trees

I use `((ObjectQuery)IQueryable).ToTraceString()` to obtain and tweak SQL code that is going to be executed by LINQ.

My problem is that unlike most IQueryable methods IQueryable.Count as defined like this:

```
    public static int Count(this IQueryable source) {
        return (int)source.Provider.Execute(
            Expression.Call(
                typeof(Queryable), "Count",
                new Type[] { source.ElementType }, source.Expression));
    }
```

executes query without compiling and returning IQueryable.
I wanted to do the trick by something like this:

```
public static IQueryable CountCompile(this IQueryable source) {
    return source.Provider.CreateQuery(
        Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable), "Count",
            new Type[] { source.ElementType }, source.Expression));
}
```

But then CreateQuery gives me the following exception:

`LINQ to Entities query expressions can only be constructed from instances that implement the IQueryable interface.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an actual working answer I came up with when I tried to so the same. The exception says "can only be constructed from instances that implement the IQueryable interface", so the answer seems simple: return a queryable something. Is that possible when returning a `.Count()`? Yes!

```
public partial class YourObjectContext
{
    private static MethodInfo GetMethodInfo(Expression<Action> expression)
    {
        return ((MethodCallExpression)expression.Body).Method;
    }
    public IQueryable<TResult> CreateScalarQuery<TResult>(Expression<Func<TResult>> expression)
    {
        return QueryProvider.CreateQuery<TResult>(
            Expression.Call(
                method: GetMethodInfo(() => Queryable.Select<int, TResult>(null, (Expression<Func<int, TResult>>)null)),
                arg0: Expression.Call(
                    method: GetMethodInfo(() => Queryable.AsQueryable<int>(null)),
                    arg0: Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(int), Expression.Constant(1))),
                arg1: Expression.Lambda(body: expression.Body, parameters: new[] { Expression.Parameter(typeof(int)) })));
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
var query = context.CreateScalarQuery(() => context.Entity.Count());
MessageBox.Show(((ObjectQuery)query).ToTraceString());
```

Basically, what this does is wrap a non-IQueryable query in a subselect. It transforms the query into

```
from dummy in new int[] { 1 }.AsQueryable()
select context.Entity.Count()
```

except lets the context's QueryProvider handle the query. The generated SQL is pretty much what you should expect:

```
SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[Entity] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [GroupBy1]
```

Comment: Great, do you know how to achieve the same on DBContext, without using its ObjectContext? When I try to use the same approach - it throws exception - Cannot create instance {Entity I want to count}, query can use only primitive values

Comment: @PhilippMunin When I try this in a project using DbContext, it works just fine. Can you include some more details showing how to get it to fail? (My project is using a fairly recent but still pre-release EF6 build, if it matters.)

Comment: I have created separate question for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385346/dbcontext-get-iqueryable-for-scalar-system-functions-count-any-sum-max

Would really appreciate if you find a way to do it

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create a query object for 'Count' since it is does not return an IQueryable (which makes sense - it returns a single value).

You have two options:

- (Recommended) Use eSQL:

  ```
  context.CreateQuery<YourEntity>("select count(1) from YourEntitySet").ToTraceString()
  ```
- Use Reflection to call a private method that doesn't perform the IQueryable check (this is wrong for obvious reasons but if you just need it for debugging, it may be handy):

  ```
  public static IQueryable CountCompile(this IQueryable source)
  {
      // you should cache this MethodInfo
      return (IQueryable)source.Provider.GetType().GetMethod("CreateQuery", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null,
                                          new[] {typeof (Expression), typeof (Type)}, null)
          .Invoke(source.Provider, new object[]
                                       {
                                           Expression.Call(
                                               typeof (Queryable), "Count",
                                               new[] {source.ElementType}, source.Expression),
                                           source.ElementType
                                       });
  }
  ```

Comment: I thought about first solution, but your second solution is quite interesting and is what I was looking for. I defined Value<T> to make Count through CountCompile complete solution:         public static T Value<T>(this IQueryable source) {
            return (T)source.Provider.Execute(source.Expression);
        }
 so that I can use query.CountCompile().Value<int>() instead of Count().

Comment: I thought that using eSQL select count(1) as substitute of Linq Count() also relies on internal implementation details because Linq Count() may or may not generate same SQL code as select count(1). I feel that using same method Count (even if private) to build expression tree is actually less implementation dependent assuming that it generates the same thing internally as public Count.