# Caching the results of LINQ queries and Count

Tags: linq-to-sql, caching

I found this little gem of an extension method [.FromCache()](http://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2008/08/07/caching-the-results-of-linq-queries/) which works nicely for most LINQ queries but falls apart when trying to cache the result of q.Count(). Because Count executes immediately it prevents the FromCache extension from saving the SQL expression and thus working it's magic.

Is there a way to generate the query expression for a q.Count() query?

The 2nd solution found here [How to obtain ToTraceString for IQueryable.Count](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8341339/31624) throws an exception.