# How to save Linq to SQL expression for q.Count()?

Tags: linq-to-sql

Because q.Count() executes immediately I'm unable to use **((ObjectQuery)IQueryable).ToTraceString()** for tracing or to use the resulting SQL expression for caching purposes.

Is there a way to generate the SQL expression for q.Count() without executing the query?

Or a way to replace the select parameters in a SQL expression with your own COUNT(*)?

Comment: Is it a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302656/how-to-obtain-totracestring-for-iqueryable-count ?

Comment: ObjectQuery is an Entity Framework thing, isn't it? Not LINQ to SQL.